# Generate a hexagon background?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a hexagonal background, but it's all one image. This generally works fine, but I may get in trouble if someone has a huge resolution. I wanted to see if it was possible to scale hexagons according to the size of your display. 
Below is an example of what kind of background i'm using.

[image]

I know you're able to repeat an image with the CSS3 repeat, but not sure how I can accomplish it with something like this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See If this link http://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html could help you do the same. Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting thanks. Definitely more then I found. I still need to figure out how to fill in the gaps however.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out how to make repeating hexagonal backgrounds thanks to you guys, and I made it so the hexagon background overlayed a blank color background so it fills in the seams.